# pandas.merge with packed arguments

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have these two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
```

I am wanting to apply the merge function on this in the following way:

```
mer={"left_on":'1key',"right_on":'rkey'}
df1.merge(df2, **mer) . <<<<<<<< unpacking variables.
```

However I am getting KeyError. Is it possible to implement the above somehow?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have a typo is `{"left_on":'lkey',"right_on":'rkey'}`, you have a 1 instead of an l

Comment: Ohh damn! Thanks @DanielMesejo